# Why doesn't the Haxe compiler complain when returning a Dynamic (String) from a function with a generic (Int) return type?

Tags: haxe

I'm wondering why the following Haxe code compiles:

```
class Test<T> { // 1
    var l:List<Dynamic> = new List<Dynamic>(); // 2
    public function new() {} // 3
    public function add(d:Dynamic):Void { l.add(d); } // 4
    public function get():T { return l.pop(); }  // 5
    public static function main() { // 6
        var t:Test<Int> = new Test<Int>(); // 7
        t.add("-"); // 8
        trace(t.get());  // 9
    } // 10
}
```

The compilation problem I see:

As seen in line 1, this class has a type parameter `T`. In line 7, it is specified that `T` is an `Int`. So the `get()` function (line 5) should only return an `Int`. However - magically - this function returns a `String` (line 9).

So ... why doesn't the compiler complain about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A dynamic value can be assigned to anything; and anything can be
>   assigned to it.

According to the Haxe manual: https://haxe.org/manual/types-dynamic.html

Since `l` is a `List<Dynamic>`, the result of `l.pop()` will also be `Dynamic`. This will be implicitly cast to `Int` when it is returned in `get()`.

I think the runtime behavior when tracing the value out at `line 9` would depend on the Haxe target.

If you change `l` into a `List<T>` and make `add()` take a parameter of type `T`, then the compiler would complain. Try this: https://try.haxe.org/#11327

```
class Test<T> { // 1
    var l:List<T> = new List<T>(); // 2
    public function new() {} // 3
    public function add(d:T):Void { l.add(d); } // 4
    public function get():T { return l.pop(); }  // 5
    public static function main() { // 6
        var t:Test<Int> = new Test<Int>(); // 7
        t.add("-"); // 8 - this won't compile anymore
        trace(t.get());  // 9
    } // 10
}
```

Comment: "A dynamic value can be assigned to anything; and anything can be assigned to it." ... Indeed HaXe seems to work like this. It is like a Boat can be cast to a Dynamic and then to a goat ...

Comment: Once you say it's `Dynamic`, all bets are off, and you lose a lot of capabilities. You noticed you lost the type checking, because `Dynamic` _could be_ an `Int`, there's no way for the compiler to know. If it was an abstract, you'd lose the abstract behavior. If it was an enum, it wouldn't be interpreted properly. So the best practice (IMO) -- avoid `Dynamic` as much as possible, or assign them back to typed variables as soon as logically possible.

Comment: `HaXe` Who does that even?